# tally() and n() in same chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate probability of a certain result (e.g. the value precip >=3) but don't know how to combine tally and n in the same chain.

this works but i'd like to not depend on `numsim`:

```
numsim=2
simdF %>%
     group_by(iter) %>%
     tally( precip >= 3 ) %>%
     mutate(
          prob=n/numsim
     )
```

why not:

```
simdF %>%
     group_by(iter) %>%
     summarise(
         freq=tally( precip >= 3 ),
         prob=freq/n()
 )


     )
```

and on that note, how can I make `3` be an argument to a function that contains this block?

Thanks!

sample data:

```
simdF=structure(list(nsim = c(1,2,1,2,1,2), iter = c(5, 5,10, 10, 30, 30), locE = c(-1, -2, -2, -1, 0, 4), locN = c(-1, 4, -2, -3, 0, 2), precip = c(1.4142135623731, 4.47213595499958, 2.82842712474619, 3.16227766016838, 0, 4.47213595499958)), .Names = c("nsim", "iter", "locE", "locN", "precip"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for `?tally`

> `tally` is a convenient wrapper for `summarise` that will either call `n` or `sum(n)` depending...

`tally` calls summarize, so it doesn't make sense to put it **inside** summarize. Just go directly to the `n()` or `sum(n)` that `tally` would. In this case, since you have a condition, use `sum`:

```
simdF %>%
     group_by(iter) %>%
     summarise(
         freq = sum(precip >= 3),
         prob = freq/n()
     )
```

As to

> how can I make 3 be an argument to a function that contains this block

The same way you'd make anything an argument:

```
your_function = function(data, precip_lower_bound = 3) { 
  data %>%
       group_by(iter) %>%
       summarise(
           freq = sum(precip >= precip_lower_bound),
           prob = freq/n()
       )
}

your_function(data = simdF, precip_lower_bound = 3)
```

Comment: i'm confused. The first mutate doesn't give you the right answer if you use n(); n() = 3 because the dF after tally() has 3 rows (I think?).   my working example also does not work in a function- `object 'precip_lower_bound' not found` .  using sum(precip >=3) makes sense now. thanks

Comment: does `n` as opposed to `n()` in my mutate example give you the number by group?

Comment: My mistake, my comment about `n` vs `n()` was before I realized `tally` added a column named `n`. As to the function, I updated my function example to be a more complete.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor I think I'm struggling because `n()` means "length of n" and `sum(n)` means "sum of n" which are two different operations. I can see why its programmed like this, to allow for conditionals, but the doc could use clarification.

Comment: Perhaps - I think the documentation assumes users are accustomed to this from base R, which is perhaps a bad assumption. Summing a boolean/logical expression is the usual way to count the number of times a condition is met - in dplyr, base R, data table, etc.